# Basic Twitter Search getting undefined error for profile_image_url

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile, twitter, undefined

Ok so here is my code, When I start parsing the  results I get an error
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile_image_url' of undefined 
I can see the object and it appears I am selecting it correctly ?? 
any suggestion ? 
thanks

```
$('#twits').live('pageinit' , function(){
alert('test');
$('#twitsubmit').click(function(){
    alert($('#query').val());

    twitSearch();
    });
    function twitSearch(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q='+ $('#query').val(),
            dataType:'jsonp',
            success: function(json_results){
                $('#twitresults ul').remove();
                $('#twitresults').append('<ul data-role="listview"></ul><p>');
                console.log(json_results);
                listItems = $('#twitresults').find('ul');
                $.each(json_results, function(key){
                    html ='<img src=' + json_results.results[key].profile_image_url +  '/>';
                    html += '<h3><a href="#">' + json_results.results[key].text + '</a></h3><p>';
                    html += '<p>From: ' + json_results.results[key].from_user + 'Created: ' + json_results.results[key].created_at + '</p>';
                    listItems.append('<li>' + html + '</li>');

                    });
                $('#twitresults ul').listview();



                }
            });
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use $.each to iterate over an array, the value passed to the callback, in your case, key, is the object itself. So try using key.profile_image_url.

Although - you also seem to be using json_results.results. So your $each may need to use json_results.results instead, ie: $.each(json_results.results, ...